# Accessing server, running on localhost, which is in container?

Tags: git, boot2docker

I have a server running at localhost:3000 in my docker container but I cannot access it from my PC.

I am trying to get this repo working in my docker

```
https://github.com/tamaspiros/advanced-chat
```

So i have my docker conatiner/image runnning and then I clone the repo

```
git clone https://github.com/tamaspiros/advanced-chat
```

then I do some installs, as instructed in the repo

```
npm install && bower install
```

then I start the server, and it starts on  IP: 127.0.0.1:3000

```
npm start

> chat@0.0.1 start /usr/share/nginx/html/web/git/advanced-chat
> node server.js

   info  - socket.io started
connect.multipart() will be removed in connect 3.0
visit https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/wiki/Connect-3.0 for alternatives
connect.limit() will be removed in connect 3.0
Express server listening on  IP: 127.0.0.1 and port 3000
```

Then I try and view the server by going to firefox `http://192.168.59.103:3000` (`127.0.0.1:3000` does not work because of boot2docker) and selecting `no proxy` in the settings. but I cannot see it I see Unable to connect.

my container port is mapped with `-p 3000:3000`
my boot2docker ip is '192.168.59.103'

`$ boot2docker ip
192.168.59.103`

I would have thought I could see the server here `192.168.59.103:3000`but not sure why I can't? maybe it is my lack of understaning in IP or something else? Can anyone advise?

**NOTE** I am running windows7 with boot2docker.

**EDIT1::**

I got that working using your advice and a bit of fiddlling at my end.

But basically I have as follows in my Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager - boot2docker-vm - settings - Network - Port Forwarding Rules:

[image]

I had to get the tcp-port3000 to look like this. But I am not fully sure what is going on. Could you kindly help me understand this please?

**Note to self:**  I got this working running meteor in a ubuntu [container](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/creating-an-app), which I had some other difficulties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need map boot2ip port for windows.

windows --> port@boot2ip vbox external ip --> port@vm --> port@dock

if vm is down, VBoxManage modifyvm "boot2docker-vm" --natpf1 "tcp-port3000,tcp,,3000,,3000";

if vm is running, VBoxManage controlvm "boot2docker-vm" natpf1 "tcp-port3000,tcp,,3000,,3000";

(I'm using Mac, but the theory is same)

Comment: do i not have that done already when I do `-p 3000:3000` when running the container?

Comment: no, which just makes the port visible for  vm, if it is not running in vbox then you are done.

Comment: sorry but is that a no and yes?

Comment: oh, sorry for the syntax. No, you haven't done it. And Yes you have done it for real machine, but here you are in virtual box, thus you need one additional step.

Comment: can you provide the commands, or be a bit more specific, sorry am a noobs. tks

Comment: Doesn't it look like a command: VBoxManage modifyvm "boot2docker-vm" --natpf1 "tcp-port3000,tcp,,3000,,3000"; 
This is the permanent configuration, you may use command boot2docker ssh -vnNTL 3000:localhost:3000 to add temporary mapping for experiments.

Comment: tks that looks to work, but I think i need loacl admin to be able to complete that command. Is there any around this? I ran the command `$ ./VBoxManage.exe modifyvm "boot2docker-vm" --natpf1 "tcp-port3000,tcp,,3000,,3000";` and then started my `boot2docker` thats when I needed admin as it was a firewall warning.

Comment: tks I got it working tks to you, but i ould love a briedf explaination to help me understand it better.

Comment: I have explained it in second line, think it over. In case you don't know how boot2docker working, boot2docker is powered by Virtual Box, it setup a minimal Linux virtual machine for you during installation. And it setup a bridge in the shell for you to proxy every command inputed into Linux shell in VM. Your docker configure tells Linux VM to mapping the port, but Linux doesn't tell VirtualBox to map the port of the VM to host system.

Comment: BTW, as you are trying with meteor, try it with docker on a VPS is much easier, take a look at lowendbox.com .